# How to get values of array element from key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-key

following is my array

```
Array(
[id] => 1
[user_id] => 30
[list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [card_id] => 6
                [amount] => 400
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [card_id] => 3
                [amount] => 500
            )

    )
)
```

from above array i want to get values of **amount** key which is in **list** key.
i want to store that values in one variable.
P.S : In **list** array it will have multiple arrays

**Edit:**
there should be sum of all amount in output. 
for example from above array sum woulld be **900**
is `$total_amount = 900`

Comment: You should provide expected output

Comment: thanks for your comment. Please see question i have edit it.

Comment: You should provide your own best effort, so we can help you help yourself

Comment: Please note that you are expected to make an attempt to achieve your desired result yourself.  If you have not done so, please take some time to do so now.  If you _have_, please include your attempt within your question, along with the result and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: thank you everybody for your valuable comments, in future if i have any question i will post with code which i have try and i also look that it should be not duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner with [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php);

`echo array_sum(array_column($array["list"], 'amount')); // 900`

See online: https://3v4l.org/EsvJO

Comment: it is just one line of code and i have try many others solution.
thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want, simple foreach:

```
$array = [
"id" => 1,
"user_id" => 30,
"list" => [
            [
                "id" => 1,
                "card_id" => 6,
                "amount" => 400,
            ],

        [

                "id" => 2,
                "card_id" => 3,
                "amount" => 500,
        ]

    ]
];

$totalAmount = 0;

foreach ($array["list"] as $array){
  $totalAmount += $array["amount"];
}

var_dump($totalAmount);
```

Result: **900**

Comment: thank you for your answer.it gives what output i want.